# Resize image using Python OpenImageIO maintain aspect ratio

Tags: python, openimageio

I'm trying to resize an image after doing some additional processing using OpenImageIO and python. However it appears this process not is as easy as PIL. In PIL i can supply a new resolution for example 512 x 512 and it will resize my image regardless of it's current pixel aspect and resize it to fit it's maximum length so it fits inside a 512x512 box. How can i do this using OpenImageIO?

Currently this will just stretch the image to fit withint 512x512.

So images that favor width should fit based on the width value:
[image]

Whereas images that favor height should fit based on the height value:
[image]

```
buf = oiio.ImageBuf(file)
data = buf.spec()
print data.width
print data.height
resized = oiio.ImageBuf(oiio.ImageSpec (512, 512, 3, oiio.FLOAT))
oiio.ImageBufAlgo.resize(resized, buf, roi=oiio.ROI.All, nthreads=4)
resized.write(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's assume that the image origin is (0,0) (i.e., it's not a "crop" or "overscan" image). We can think about images that are wider than they are long ("landscape"), or longer than wide ("portrait").

I think you want something like the following, which uses the goal width for landscape and the goal height for portrait, and recomputes the proper size in the other direction:

```
goal_width = ...
goal_height = ...

buf = oiio.ImageBuf(file)
spec = buf.spec()
w = spec.width
h = spec.height
aspect = float(w) / float(h)
if aspect >= 1.0 :
    # source image is landscape (or square)
    goal_height = int(h * goal_height / w)
else :
    # source image is portrait
    goal_width = (w * goal_width / h)

resized = oiio.ImageBuf(oiio.ImageSpec (goal_width, goal_height, spec.nchannels, spec.format))
oiio.ImageBufAlgo.resize(resized, buf)
resized.write(output)
```

That's off the top of my head, you should test it and adjust if I've made mistakes. But that's the gist.

Aside: note that when I create the resized buf, I used the number of channels and data format of the original file, which is a bit more robust than hard-coding it to 3 chans float as you did in the original.